# DevTools v4 is incompatible with this version of React

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to use standalone React Native Debugger. I installed it by following [this instruction](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger). Run command `$ brew update && brew cask install react-native-debugger`.

Then I launch it along with my app running on emulator. I see this:

[image]

As you can see it says :

DevTools v4 is incompatible with this version of React
Either upgrade React or install React DevTools v3:

```
npm install -d react-devtools@^3
```

So, I did run the above command & restart the debugger, but still see the same message.

Then I tried to install the latest React by command :

```
npm install react@latest react-dom@latest prop-types@latest
```

Then, I restart the debugger but still see that message. I get confused, how to get rid of that message?

Here is my *package.json*

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~37.0.3",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.1.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: You have installed `react-native-debugger` using brew. You will first need to uninstall it. Then, the npm install should be using the global `-g` flag not the dev-dependency `-d` flag. And, although you've updated the react version, the react-native version is behind by quite a bit. Only 0.62 is supported by the latest dev tools. I'd suggest trying to install the old dev tools first and see how it goes.

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem, but using React Native Expo, just fixed it using previous React Native Debugger version (v10). It should work with your React Native Version.

Here's the link to download from the official repository: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.1.tar.gz